# Can I simulate text selection with the mouse in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mouse, simulate

I would like to select text on the page by simulating a left mouse button down and drag it to a specified x,y location (in pixels)

Can this be done with JavaScript?

Comment: have you got this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think its possible to control the mouse in this way using JavaScript.

However, you can select parts of a document directly using JavaScript. For example:

```
var h3s = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(h3s[0]);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

would select the first h3 element.

Also see: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html for more info about building ranges.

To select the entire body of a document, you can use:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(body);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

To select the 3rd character of, say, the 4th paragraph in a document, try:

```
var p4 = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[3].firstChild;
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(p4, 2);
range.setEnd(p4, 3);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

Comment: Can I also select until the middle of the element.. like, letter #3?

Also, is your example capable to select lets say a body element, that contains various divs, fonts, etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Select text between 2 elements. Support selection of continuous elements.
 * @param {Object} element1 begin element.
 * @param {Object} element2 end element.
 */
function selectBetweenTwoElements(element1, element2) {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        /* all browsers, except IE 8 and IE 7 */
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(element1, 0);
        range.setEnd(element2, 1);
        selection.addRange(range);
    } else {
        /* works fine in IE 8 / IE 7 */
        if (document.body.createControlRange) {
            var range1 = document.body.createTextRange();
            range1.moveToElementText(element1);
            
            var range2 = document.body.createTextRange();
            range2.moveToElementText(element2);
            
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.setEndPoint("StartToStart", range1);
            range.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range2);
            range.select();
        }
    }
}
```